# Splitting column data into two variables using regex in R

Tags: r, regex, split

I have this dataset which I require to split 1 column into 2 variables - flavor and type:

```
| column_1           | count |
| ------------------ | ----- |
| total mango juice  | 01    |
| orange juice       | 02    |
| strawberry jam     | 09    |
| total strawberry   | 06    |
| strawberry jelly   | 05    |
| total jelly        | 04    |
```

I am hoping to make the table to look like this:

```
| flavour    | type   | count |
| -----------| ------ | ----- |
| mango      | juice  | 01    |
| orange     | juice  | 02    |
| strawberry | jam    | 09    |
| strawberry | N/A    | 06    |
| strawberry | jelly  | 05    |
| N/A        | jelly  | 04    |
```

I've tried scouring around for solutions and trying it on R studio but to no avail. However there is a requirement that we have to split the column using **regex**.

Does that also mean I have to define the new variables?

Comment: Is there only _this dataset_? Are there only those three flavors? Are there only those three types? Is `total` the only extra word?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `separate` after creating a delimiter and removing the 'total'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(column_1 = str_remove(str_replace(column_1, 
      "(.*)\\s+(juice|jelly|jam)$", "\\1,\\2"), '^total\\s*')) %>% 
     separate(column_1, into = c('flavour', 'type'))
```

-output

```
 flavour  type count
1      mango juice     1
2     orange juice     2
3 strawberry   jam     9
4 strawberry  <NA>     6
5 strawberry jelly     5
6            jelly     4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(column_1 = c("total mango juice", "orange juice", 
"strawberry jam", "total strawberry", "strawberry jelly", "total jelly"
), count = c(1L, 2L, 9L, 6L, 5L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```